# The $\Delta$ in Dimension Regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

In dimension regularization, we often encounter the integral:
$$\int \frac{d^Dl_E}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{l_E^k}{(l_E^2+\Delta)^n}$$
where the subscript $E$ stands for Euclidean signature.
The result of this integral is:
$$\int \frac{d^Dl_E}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{l_E^k}{(l_E^2+\Delta)^n} = \frac{1}{(4\pi)^{D/2}}\Big( \frac{1}{\Delta} \Big)^{n-\frac{k+D}{2}}\frac{\Gamma(n-\frac{k+D}{2})\Gamma(\frac{k+D}{2})}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(\frac{D}{2})}$$

I proved this using the condition $\Delta>0$. Will this identity also hold for $\Delta \leq 0$?

Comment: For $\Delta\le 0$ the integral diverges.

Comment: For $\Delta\leq 0$ you would always encounter extra divergences at $l^2_E=-\Delta$.